# Isn't taking the mean of a pandas column of boolean values supposed to return the proportion that is True?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, mean

So I took the mean of a pandas data frame column that contains boolean values.  I've done this in the past multiple times and understood that it would return the proportion that is True.  But when I wrote it in this particular instance, it didn't work.  It returns the proportion that is False and not only that, the denominator it uses doesn't seem to relate to anything.  I have no idea where it pulls the denominator from to calculate the proportion value.  I discovered it works the way I want it to when I remove the second line of code (datadf = datadf[1:])

```
# get current row value minus previous row value and returns True if > 0 
datadf['increase'] = datadf.index.map(lambda x: datadf.loc[x]['price'] - datadf.loc[x-1]['price'] > 0 if x > 0 else None)
# remove first row because it gives 'None'
datadf = datadf[1:]
# calculate proportion that is True
accretionscore = datadf['increase'].mean()
```

This is the output

```
        date    price      increase
1 2020-09-28  488.51          True
2 2020-09-29  489.33          True
3 2020-09-30  490.43          True
4 2020-10-01  499.51          True
5 2020-10-02  478.99         False

correct value: 0.8
value given: 0.2
```

When I try adding another sample that's when things get weirder:

```
        date    price      increase
1 2020-09-27  479.78         False
2 2020-09-28  488.51          True
3 2020-09-29  489.33          True
4 2020-09-30  490.43          True
5 2020-10-01  499.51          True
6 2020-10-02  478.99         False

correct value: 0.6666666666666666
value given:  0.16666666666666666
```

they don't even add up to 1!
I'm so confused.  Can anyone tell me what is going on?  How does taking out the second line fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if you want to convert from *boolean* to *int*, then you just can use:

```
datadf['increase'] = datadf['increase'].astype(int)
```

and this way things will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If we run your code, you can see that `datadf['increase']` is an object instead of a boolean, so taking mean on this is most likely converting the categories to a number and so on.. basically something weird:

```
import pandas as pd
datadf = pd.DataFrame({'price':[470,488.51,489.33,490.43,499.51,478.99]})
datadf['increase'] = datadf.index.map(lambda x: datadf.loc[x]['price'] - datadf.loc[x-1]['price'] > 0 if x > 0 else None)

datadf['increase']
Out[8]:
0     None
1     True 
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: increase, dtype: object

datadf['increase'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

From what I can see, you want True / False on whether the row is larger than its preceding, so do:

```
datadf['increase'] = datadf.price > datadf.price.shift(1)
datadf['increase'].dtype
dtype('bool')
```

And we just omit the first row by doing:

```
datadf['increase'][1:].mean()
0.8
```

Comment: thank you your code is much more concise than mine.